Is "voltage across an inductor" actually real, or a convenient engineer trick?
Recently in electricity and magnetism class I learned how to solve basic circuits with Faraday's Law. You can't really go wrong with it; define currents in branches, charges/voltages on capacitors, evaluate loops, and you got your system of equations.
Thing is, I noticed something odd to me. For a long time I've known the basic assumption that for an inductor, $V = L \frac {\mathrm di} {\mathrm dt}$. Let's say we have a circuit with only a resistor R and an inductor L, with a current i in some defined positive direction. If we look at Faraday's Law:

$$
\oint \vec{E} \cdot \vec{\mathrm dr} = -\frac {\mathrm d} {\mathrm dt} \int \vec B \cdot \vec{\mathrm ds}
$$
The left hand side equals $iR$, because the electric field, by Ohm's Law, follows $\vec E = \rho \vec J$. Letting $a$ be the cross-sectional area of the resistor, and $\rho$ be its resistivity, we integrate across it:
$$
\int_R \frac {\rho i} a dl = \frac \rho l i = iR
$$
Alright, great. The rest of the circuit doesn't contribute to the left-hand side, because ideal wires and inductors have $\rho = 0$, and again, $\vec E = \rho \vec J$, so no electric field. Now what about the magnetic flux part of the law? The magnetic flux across a circuit is affected by any external magnetic field (not this time) and the self-inductance of the circuit, which for simplicity we assume is all concentrated within the inductor L, and the flux is proportional to the current in the circuit, i.
$$
-\frac {\mathrm d} {\mathrm dt} \int \vec B \cdot \vec{\mathrm ds} = -\frac {\mathrm d} {\mathrm dt}(Li) \\~\\~\\
iR = -L \frac {\mathrm di} {\mathrm dt} \\~\\~\\
iR + L \frac {\mathrm di} {\mathrm dt} = 0
$$
Now, look at that. The voltage drop across a resistor, plus the "voltage drop" across an inductor, added up to 0. This is Kirchoff's Loop Law, if we pretend that the voltage drop across the inductor really does equal that expression. I used absolutely nothing to do with Kirchoff's Loop Law. This was only Faraday's Law.
My understanding from this is that using $V = L \frac {\mathrm di} {\mathrm dt}$ is a trick that lets you use Faraday's Law disguised as Kirchoff's Loop Law without needing to think about any integrals, making circuit analysis much simpler. Is this really all it is? Is there something I'm misunderstanding? You can't just formally say that an inductor has a voltage difference across it just because you take the inductive term of the equation to the other side and go "Hey look, it kinda looks like it came from the electric field integral, that's convenient!"

This is a good question. To make it an excellent one please add two things: 1) A diagram of the circuit under consideration and 2) a drawing of the curve that you're integrating over. I spent many hours puzzling over pretty much exactly what you're asking here and I'd like to write an answer and will do if you can add those two things.

There's a whole internet controversy about this :-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9LuVBfwvzA. My takeaway is that, basically, you are right, this is a "trick" to simplify analysis of circuits, but incredibly useful. See also the Feynman lectures Vol 2 chapter 22.

In the end, yes, it's a "trick", but so is $V = I R$ (i.e. Ohm's law). These are all convenient results coming from Maxwell's equations under certain assumptions about the objects in the circuit. In fact, if you have magnetic flux through the loops in your circuit, Kirchhoff's laws aren't even correct unless you add the appropriate terms coming from Maxwell's equations.

@DanielSank Done

You are referring to what is sometimes called "exteneded KVL" or "modified KVL". It works in lumped circuit theory and it is 'a trick' to disguise Faraday's law in the more familiar guise of KVL. See my answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734449/using-kvl-in-a-changing-magnetic-field/734496#734496 and the other linked posts. The key takeaway is that voltage becomes path dependent and you need to specify a path.

To clarify, by "trick", I meant the idea of the lumped circuit model involving separating the circuit element into an "inside" and "outside" -- which you should know also implies I would (and do) also use the word "trick" to describe other clever procedures that simplify problems, like replacing a collection of masses by their center of mass in Newtonian mechanics. I definitely did not mean the word "trick" to imply that the result is not mathematically rigorous.

it is not a trick, it is the definition of a lumped element in a linear circuit, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/431502/can-kirchhoffs-voltage-law-be-applied-here/431539#431539

@Peltio it's not merely a trick, and there is nothing extended in KVL with inductors. Voltage in circuit theory is a two point function with definite value, difference of electric potential. It is path-independent, only endpoints and positive direction-dependent. IEC voltage is a different concept; yes, people also call it "voltage", but its path ambiguity is superfluous in circuits, since nobody is interested in different voltages due to different paths connecting two terminals. We are interested only in the one voltage value that appears in KVL, equal to p. d. between the element terminals.

@JánLalinský we clearly disagree on which is the 'best' definition of voltage. I gave some reasons in our previous exchanges, and I still need to finish the drawings to illustrate my point in my dedicated answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/446454/does-kirchhoffs-law-always-hold/832049#832049 . In the meantime look at the addition I made at the end of my answer to this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734449/using-kvl-in-a-changing-magnetic-field?noredirect=1&lq=1 - Last figure: do you agree you that a person in the room can't tell what 'your' voltage is?

No, this is not a trick at all. This follows naturally from simplifying Maxwells equations using the lumped element model and the assumptions of circuit theory.
See figure 11.3.3 in the MIT EM textbook and the associated derivation. In summary, as long as there exists a surface around the lumped element (inductor) that meets some basic assumptions, it does not matter at all what goes on inside that surface. The power delivered to the lumped element depends only on the current and voltage at the terminals. The assumptions in that derivation are implied by two of the three foundational assumptions of circuit theory.

You can't just formally say that an inductor has a voltage difference across it

Yes, you can. The derivation shows that it doesn’t matter what happens inside the surface. You can have all manner of changing magnetic flux or displacement currents. Outside the surface the fields and the power transfer does not care at all what happens inside. It is irrelevant if it is a resistor, capacitor, inductor, or even a transformer. All of them are the same and so they are all legitimately and without trickery called by the same word.

This is absolutely correct. There is no "trick"

@BobD the 'trick' is to pretend that KVL still works, while in reality it only works locally, in selected regions of space that do not link any relevant time-varying magnetic field. As a matter of fact, in general KVL does not work (Lewin's ring is one example, but in any circuit in which there's a changing magnetic field linked by conducting loops - essentially half of an EMC course - one has to kiss KVL goodbye). I know many people try go back to KVL by 'materializing' a lumped component here and there, but that's more often than not cause of confusion.

@Peltio nobody claims the KVL rule works in circuits with varying external flux or other external EMF.  The modern KVL is a rule that produces the same equations as the original Kirchhoff's second circuital law (which is more general and holds even for circuits with varying flux) in case the circuit is made of lumped elements and EMF due to changing external magnetic flux is negligible.

The key words here are "lumped element."  That's the specific set of assumptions which let you treat the inductor as one "lumped" element, with a voltage change across it.  The value of that voltage change, $L\frac{di}{dt}$ can be computed from Faraday's law, as long as the lumped element assumptions hold.

You took me out of context at the end there, my emphasis was that it doesn't seem like a sound argument to me to just say the algebra kind of acts like there ought to be a voltage difference across an inductor when you move some terms to another side of the equation. I said that as to say "There has to be a better argument" and this sure seems like it. I'd never heard of lumped elements before. Is a lumped element a kind of abstraction of a component, kind of like how when we say "resistor" we don't care about a lot of specific details about it, and just say it's some wire with a resistivity?

@Peltio There's nothing wrong with KVL. When you use KVL, you are essentially pledging to properly account for induction. Unfortunately, that accounting is often difficult.

@JohnDoty there is nothing wrong as long as we stay in lumped circuit theory. I have made my points in the answer I have linked but it's now hidden  in chat and does not appear in the links on the side.

@Peltio You may always separate the electric field into the component due to charge and the component due to induction. The component due to charge will have a corresponding scalar potential, and KVL trivially applies. With a bit more abstraction you wind up in the Coulomb gauge...

@JohnDoty yes, KVL (or rather Kirchhoff's scalar potential difference Law) always applies to the scalar potential component of voltage. The problem is that the scalar potential difference is: not gauge invariant, not what you measure with a voltmeter, changes with the presence and position of external (not linked) time-varying magnetic fields, only describes half of the physical system, and does not obey to Ohm's law and Joule's law. The physically relevant quantity is voltage. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/446454/does-kirchhoffs-law-always-hold/832049#832049 (pictures soon...)

@Peltio Of course it's not gauge invariant: it involves choosing the appropriate (Coulomb) gauge.

@Peltio A routine phenomenon on the bench is to observe a voltage between a point and itself. You must account for induction...

If we define a "voltage" as a "difference in electrostatic potential between two points", then it is true that there is no "voltage" across an inductor, because if
$$\oint_C \vec{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{l}\neq0$$
then the electric field is not conservative and one cannot define $\varphi$ such that $\vec{E}=-\nabla\varphi$. There cannot be a potential difference if there is no potential. But, there will be an electromotive force or emf, understood as a work done per unit charge
$$\mathcal{E}= \oint_C \vec{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{l}.$$
Notice that voltage is also work done per unit charge
$$V = -\int_A^B \vec{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{l}=-\int_A^B \frac{\vec{F}}{q}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{l} =\frac{W}{q}.$$
The negative sign disappears if you conveniently choose the path to be against the electric force. At least in my opinion, it's true that calling $V=L\frac{di}{dt}$ a "voltage" is a "trick", slight deception - but the underlying concept of emf is so similar, it would be pragmatically suicidal to not call it so.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


My understanding from this is that using $V = L \frac {\mathrm di} {\mathrm dt}$ is a trick that lets you use Faraday's Law disguised as Kirchoff's Loop Law without needing to think about any integrals, making circuit analysis much simpler. Is this really all it is? Is there something I'm misunderstanding? You can't just formally say that an inductor has a voltage difference across it just because you take the inductive term of the equation to the other side and go "Hey look, it kinda looks like it came from the electric field integral, that's convenient!"

Not merely a "trick". It's true it's the "way of the trade" in electrical engineering, and it works in general in any lumped element circuit, and simplifies the whole procedure of finding and writing down the circuit equations.
But it is also useful to remember the result that potential drop on ideal inductor in positive direction is always $L\frac{di}{dt}$. That is not a trick; it's a solid, well-argued result of EM theory. Moreover, all circuit elements, including inductors, have definite potential drop on them (possibly variable in time), because of what electric potential is: a single-valued function of position in 3D space, defined at all its points (assuming charge distribution is regular enough, not having point or line sources). In lumped element circuits, we can express these potential drops in terms of $\mathscr{E},Q,I,\dot{I}$ and get useful circuit equations. In circuits where external induced EMF wreaks havoc, potential differences are still definite, we just can't express them as universal functions of $\mathscr{E},Q,I,\dot{I}$, because the external induced electric field affects how current in each element behaves, and how this goes, depends on details of the external induced electric field.

Recently in electricity and magnetism class I learned how to solve basic circuits with Faraday's Law. You can't really go wrong with it; define currents in branches, charges/voltages on capacitors, evaluate loops, and you got your system of equations.

Faraday's law gives us value of induced EMF in a closed path, in terms of rate of change of magnetic flux or current. It does not give us the fact that magnitude of this EMF equals $Ri$, or the KVL equation
$$
Ri + L\frac{di}{dt} = 0.\tag{*}
$$
This equation can be obtained in several different ways. Your derivation uses more than Faraday's law: it uses also generalized Ohm's law in both the resistor and the inductor and also it assumes zero resistance and finite current density in inductor coils. Your derivation is correct, but puts a lot of importance into Faraday's law, and this is not completely general, or how ordinary lumped circuit equations are obtained in practice. The reason is, the Faraday law gives only induced EMF, but there are other kinds of EMF. There is a systematic way to get an equation relating potential differences in a closed path for all kinds of circuits, even if there is no inductor in the circuit and there are other devices or different EMF sources, such as batteries.
The first systematic way (and the most general one, applicable also to circuits that are not lumped element circuits) to derive the above equation (*) is the original Kirchhoff second circuital law, which states that sum of EMFs acting in a closed path equals sum of terms $R_kI_k$ over all elements $k$ in the closed path, where $R_k$ is ohmic resistance of $k$-th element, and $I_k$ is current flowing through it. Faraday's law can be used to show that induced EMF due to inductor, in a closed path of the circuit, is $-L\frac{di}{dt}$, and then Kirchhoff's second circuital law can be written as:
$$
-L\frac{di}{dt} = Ri
$$
which is equivalent to (*).
The second systematic way, which is more modern, but is useful only in lumped element circuits, is to use the KVL (Kirchhoff Voltage Law), which is actually not a law, but a rule to get a subset of circuit equations. KVL says that sum of potential drops (= voltages in the context of the circuit theory) in a closed path equals zero. This is obviously true since electric potential is a single-valued function of position; but it is nevertheless very useful, since it relates potential drops in the circuit which we can often express in terms of battery EMF, or charge (capacitor), or current(resistor), or time derivative of current (ideal inductor).
Here, we need potential drop on an ideal inductor. For a real inductor, this depends on details such as ohmic resistance and capacitance of the inductor, but for ideal inductor, potential drop is $L\frac{di}{dt}$ (with plus sign). Why? Because net electric field $\mathbf E$ in the coils vanishes, and thus when we define the conservative part $\mathbf E_c$ and the induced part $\mathbf E_i$, so that $\mathbf E= \mathbf E_c + \mathbf E_i$ (e.g. via the Helmholtz decomposition of total field $\mathbf E$ or just defining $\mathbf E_c$ as the familiar  integral over charge distribution in space), in the inductor coils, we have:
$$
\mathbf E_c = -\mathbf E_i.
$$
We can do a line integral of both sides of this equation over a path that starts at one terminal of the inductor and ends at another, and goes through the conducting medium the coils are made of, in the designated positive direction; then we get the equation
$$
\int_{inductor~coils} \mathbf E_c \cdot d\mathbf s = -\int_{inductor~coils} \mathbf E_i\cdot d\mathbf s.
$$
The left-hand side is (by definition) drop of electric potential $\varphi$ when going from one terminal to another, which we designate as $V$; and the integral on the right-hand side can be shown (calculations of inductance for given geometry) to be equal to $-L\frac{di}{dt}$ for some positive constant $L$. So after one minus cancels another minus, we get
$$
V= L\frac{di}{dt}.
$$
For a resistor in lumped element circuits where current in the resistor is acted upon only by a conservative field $\mathbf E_c$ (no external induced EMF is allowed, so $\mathbf E_i$ vanishes in the resistor), drop of potential is equal to integral of net electric field, which is $Ri$. The KVL is
$$
V_{resistor} + V_{inductor} = 0
$$
and with the results above, this implies
$$
Ri + L\frac{di}{dt} = 0,
$$
which is the same as (*).

Now, look at that. The voltage drop across a resistor, plus the "voltage drop" across an inductor, added up to 0. This is Kirchoff's Loop Law, if we pretend that the voltage drop across the inductor really does equal that expression. I used absolutely nothing to do with Kirchoff's Loop Law. This was only Faraday's Law.

It's more correctly called a potential drop, but more importantly, we do not need to "pretend" - it really is equal to $L\frac{di}{dt}$. I'm tempted to say you can check this in a real $RL$ circuit with an oscilloscope: you can measure and record potential drop on the inductor $V$, and this is obviously minus the potential drop  on the resistor. You can then calculate current as $i=-V/R$, and you can then check that indeed $L\frac{\Delta i}{\Delta t}$ has very close value to $V$.

I'll take more time later to read this more deeply, but I want to point out I absolutely can solve a circuit with a battery using Faraday's Law alone, at least the way my class has taught me. If you integrate $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{dr}$ across a battery from its + terminal to its - terminal, by definition of what the battery is doing, you just went from a higher potential to a lower potential, and the battery's contribution is its voltage difference, say V, because $-(V_- - V_+) = V$

@HydroPage integral of $\vec{E}$ across battery terminals gives potential difference only when there is no induced electric field in the battery. This is a good approximation in most cases, but in Kirchhoff's second circuital law, no such assumption has to be made, and one can have external induced electric field everywhere, including the battery.

@HydroPage Faraday's law only gives us induced EMF, which is integral of induced electric field in the circuit, it does not give us what happens to current. We need something else, either generalized Ohm's law $\vec{E} = \rho \vec{j}$ or Kirchhoff's second circuital law, which has also been called generalization of Ohm's law, because it extend the ohmic relation between current and resistance to cases where current is acted upon by any EMF, not just by potential difference.
